# Is it a wrapper or delegate or agent?

Tags: c++

I have a class to do the task

```
class A
{
public:
    void doSomething();
};
```

And I have another class containing a pointer to `A` and do the task through the `A` and has other members which is not just a pimpl (sorry for not making my question clear in the 1st edition)

```
class B
{
public:
    void doSomething() { mA->doSomething(); }
    ...

private:
    A* mA;
    ...
};
```

How to call `B`? A wrapper, delegate or agent? Or they are same concept just different names? How to call `A`, like The delegated?

To make it more specific,  in my case, the B is in GUI level and A is in domain logic level. How to call these? And if B has it own data and the data can be used to generate a A? How to call this relation? Thanks.

Comment: @billz: it's not PIMPL, the body of B::do, which is given inside the class definition, requires the compiler to know about A::do. This makes compiler require the definition of A while compiling the definition of B, which defeats the goal of PIMPL.

Comment: @liori A remarkable insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of `B` cannot be inferred with certainty from this small code snippet. Structurally, this is a case of class [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), which can be used to make wrappers, decorators, adapters, proxies/surrogates, and so on, depending on the purpose of the class `B`.

If `B` inherited `A`, it would be a decorator or a wrapper. If `B` contained an implicit conversion operator to `A`, it would be a surrogate or a proxy. If `B` used `A` to implement behavior of some other contract, it would be an adapter. Note, however, that all these concepts are higher level than the "construction primitives" of the language, such as inheritance and composition, so you need a wider usage context of `A` and `B` among other classes of your system to decide which one it is.

Comment: It is very knowledgeable. In my case, the `B` is in GUI level and `A` is in domain logic level. How to call these? And if `B` has it own data and the data can be used to generate a `A`? How to call this relation? Thank.

Comment: @user1899020 If `B` is UI and `A` is domain logic, you can adapt the vocabulary of the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), and call `A` a *model*, and `B` an `A`'s *view*.

Answer (score 2):

A delegate is a helper object -- it lets you change the behavior of the delegating object without subclassing. It's a well known design pattern.

A wrapper is not the same as a delegate. A wrapper is a class that's used to change the interface to an object for some reason, as in the façade pattern.

What you're showing is simple containment -- code like that could be used to implement either of the patterns above, or something else. We can't tell whet the relationship between the objects is, so can't say that it's a certain specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting wrapped up with semantics. You have a class that happens to control another class - does it really mean what it is called?

Analogous to having an uploader class that has a `start` method, along with an `uploaderQueue` class that has the same `start` method. The queue manages the files and calls their `upload` method where required.

This is delegation - let the work happen where it needs to.

Please don't get consumed by 'design patterns'

Comment: What the relationship is called *does* matter because having the right name lets us communicate about the relationship more easily.  This is the point of design patterns. The only problem here is that there's not enough detail here to say what the relationship is.